# Unexpected change in the value of a StreamProvider, after I change the value of a copy variable

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I assign the value of my `streamProvider` to a new variable object  `usersList`... then I change a property `tel` in that newly created variable... but, surprise... the `Provider` itself also changes and I can no longer access the last value of that stream... strange... I thought that flutter is by value not by reference...

Otherweise, my `StreamProvider` seems properly wired to my `Firestore`: when value in DB is changed, it propagates properly to app which is the expected behaviour.

**Help... How can I change my object copy without interfering with the Provider?**

**Code:**

```
@override  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("===== initial provider value: ${Provider.of<UsersList>(context).item("jaiKMOS5EHRTxc8wlorpNyLruf1").tel}");
    UsersList usersList = Provider.of<UsersList>(context); //I create a brand new variable where I assign value of Provider
    usersList.item("jaiKMOS5EHRTxc8wlorpNyLruf1").tel = "NewVal";  //I change my own local variable (not expecting Provider to change

    // ***** Why does the following value change ????
    print("===== updated provider value: ${Provider.of<UsersList>(context).item("jaiKMOS5EHRTxc8wlorpNyLruf1").tel}");
    return Text("");
}
```

**Log:**

> I/flutter ( 7477): ===== initial provider value: 511-822-5571
>
> I/flutter ( 7477): ===== updated provider value: NewVal

**StreamProvider:**

```
  @override  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<UsersList>(
      create: (context) => _dbService.getUsersStream, initialData:null,
      child: HomePage());
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is just a placeholder. You have an object and the variable just stores that object there. 2 variables can point to the same object, and that's what's happening.

When you call Provider, it will just give you back a reference to an object (`UsersList`), that you defined inside the Provider constructor (`_dbService.getUsersStream`). Since you are using `create:`, `Provider` will call that creation function lazily (when you need it for the first time), and then it will store that value internally. `create` WILL NOT be called each time you call `Provider.of<UsersList>(context)`.

So your variable `usersList` points to the same object that `Provider` holds internally.

Comment: Thanks Michel @user:1227166 . So I changed the `create` into `value`:  ` @override  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<UsersList>.value(
      value: _dbService.getUsersStream, initialData:null,
      child: HomePage());
  }` but still same issue... How can I create an object copy that I can change safely?

Comment: That's not how Provider works, read the docs. Value will just inject a value you created by yourself. Provider doesn't have a factory method that will recreate an object.

Comment: thanks @Michel Feinstein.  So, I guess, I just need to define myself how to create a clone from the provider, right?

Comment: It depends on what you want, maybe get_it is best suited for your needs.